# How to make a flag to change automatically after 24 hours

Tags: java, spring, java-8

So if user click on disable button should be some flag active for 24 hours that it is disabled and customers do not see the app, then it is automatically re-enabled so it is visible again.
I would like this may be to be a boolean, but not sure,
So is there any simple fix for this or I should control in page load if this true or false, but still I need this somehow to measure the hours, passing so I can show the user in the dynamic way how hours are left, Thanks, and I would appreciate any idea you might have.

Comment: There is something very important missing.  You have not explained what kind of "app" this is, and where / how it is normally "visible".  For example, if this is a webapp or website, it is doubtful that you can make it "invisible" to a specific user without making it "invisible" to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring,You can use @Scheduled annotation to execute a function periodically, even user hasn't done any click actions.

```
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * ? 2019")
   public void runIt(){
        //write something to execute periodically
   }
```

The above scheduler run At 12:00 pm (noon) every day during the year 2019.
For setting your own schedule you can refer

[Scheduled](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) 
and 
[Cron params](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions)

Or
If you want call a method only after an action, you can use the Java Timer and TimerTask Classes refer this link [Java Timer Task](https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)